# imgCheck.ImageUrl = "/images/Blank.jpg"; wont work

Tags: c#

Title explains it all. I am using this code at the top. It works. But you will see my comments at the bottom where it does not do anything. Everything else in the section works, just not that last line.

for testing, I created a separate button with the same line, it worked, but In the text changed handler for that specific text box, it just doesn't do anything.

thanks for the help.

```
 using System; 
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using System.Linq; 
 using System.Web; 
 using System.Web.UI; 
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 

 namespace Visitor_Tracking 
 { 

     public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
     { 

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
         { 
             //if (double.Pharse txtboxVisitorCode.TextChanged += ) 
             { 
                 txtboxVisitorCode.Focus(); 
                 imgCheck.ImageUrl = "/images/Blank.jpg"; 
             } 

         } 

         protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
         { 
             imgCheck.ImageUrl = "/images/GreenCheck.jpg"; 
         } 

         protected void txtboxVisitorCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
         { 
             if (txtboxVisitorCode.Text == "1234") 
             { 
                 imgCheck.ImageUrl = "/images/GreenCheck.jpg"; 
                 lblPlate.Visible = true; 
                 txtboxPlate.Visible = true; 
                 btnPlate.Visible = true; 
                 txtboxPlate.Focus(); 
             } 
             else 
             { 
                 imgCheck.ImageUrl = "/images/RedX.jpg"; 
                 txtboxVisitorCode.Text = ""; 
             } 

         } 

         protected void txtboxPlate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
         { 

             lblPlate.Visible = false; 
             txtboxPlate.Visible = false; 
             txtboxPlate.Text = ""; 
             txtboxVisitorCode.Text = ""; 
             btnPlate.Visible = false; 
             btnPlate.Visible = false; 
             // 
             // 
             // 
             // this line does nothing 
             imgCheck.ImageUrl = "/images/Blank.jpg"; 
             // 
             // 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Is imgCheck getting set to invisible for some strange manner?

Comment: Nop. what I posted is the entire app. it stays visible, but the image just doesn't change.

Comment: You need to add a "if (!IsPostBack) { ... }" condition in Page load event

Comment: IsPostBack was it. Although I set it on the object not in code. I Had to do this with the other box, I feel silly I forgot. 

thank you.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: title explains nothing